# How to create default PHP file with windows batch command

Tags: php, batch-file

im trying to create a batch script that generates a pre set php file for me (for creating new pages)

the code currently looks like this

```
@echo off
echo "New Page Maker"
set /p Input=Name of new page:
mkdir .\views\%input%
test  > .\views\%input%\index.php

mkdir .\views\%input%\css
(
echo <?php header("Content-type:text/css"); ?>
echo <?php require(dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)))."/public/css/getsitedata.php");?>
) > .\views\%input%\css\style.php
```

if i wrap the echos in "'s the style.php gets created but the content is in "'s too

is there any way to get the echo to work properly.  I've search and search and cant find anything quite the same, I have tried adding carrots ^ to ever < > to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you make a default php file set and, well, you know, just copy it?

But if you insist..

```
echo ^<?php header("Content-type:text/css"); ?^> > .\views\%input%\css\style.php
echo ^<?php require(dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)))."/public/css/getsitedata.php");?^> >> .\views\%input%\css\style.php
```

Comment: right, we started pondering other ways to do this once we got stuck on the "'s being inserted into the created file, and my partner is making a php script that does it all.  I'm just determined to get a batch file working to do this lol.

Comment: and there are multiple files that need to be created and lines edited per file once the files are made thats why a batch or script is the way to do this.

Comment: I edited my answer. just use >> to insert at the end of an existing file. Also, consider moving to linux ;-) bash is more powerfull and fun to do these kind of things in.

Comment: thank you =) so my problem was i cant wrap it, cause i did try the carrots